# Lightning component - pulsate on re-render (data change)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a simple table that I continually update by polling database.

I want to alert user on data change - new record has been added, order has changed or single field has re-rendered.

What could be a good solution here?

As I understand Lightning has nothing built in here so I'd need to build something from scratch:

1. Extract deltas - I can probably rig something here myself
2. Apply some animation - probably jiggle or shake from here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/animation/gallery/

I do wonder how to apply that for single cell tho. Passing animation name   as property perhaps?

Comment: I think the right approach for your needs is using the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) - you can learn from [TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_streaming)  also

Comment: @ItaiShmida I'd rather keep polling - this is already in implemented. What I am concerned about is rendering part.